# Define this function outside of a loop

Tags: javascript, sonarqube

I have the following code :

```
for (var entry in metadata) {
     if (metadata.hasOwnProperty(entry)) {
         var varName = metadata[entry].variableName;
         if (metadata[entry].multipleValues === "false") {
             if (angular.isDefined(vm[varName]) && (vm[varName] !== null) && vm[varName].id !== null) {
                 filters.push(factory.buildEntry(metadata[entry].variableName, vm[varName].id, null, factory.filterOperators.textContains));
             }
         } else {
             if (angular.isDefined(vm[varName]) && (angular.isArray(vm[varName])) && (vm[varName].length > 0)) {
                 filters.push(factory.buildEntry(metadata[entry].variableName, null, vm[varName].map(function (item) {
                     return item.id;
                 }), factory.filterOperators.textContains));
             }
         }
     }
}
```

But SonarQube keeps telling me to `Define this function outside of a loop.`, and the only function I have inside this loop is the anonymous function I pass to the `Array.prototype.map()` method :

```
function (item) {
    return item.id;
}
```

Which would be useless if I define it outside my loop since it's body only contains one line of code.

Why I'm getting this error ? and how can I tell SonarQube to skip it.

Comment: You figured it out by yourself the reason of the error. `how can I tell SonarQube to skip it?` --> If possible, there is probably some kind of comment you can add. Otherwise, you'd have to mark it as false-positive at the SonarQube interface.

Comment: Which version of SonarJS are you using? There is ticket https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARJS-772 fixed in SonarJS 3.0 which is seems like your case

Answer (score 0):

How about you define it outside the loop

```
var mapFunction = function (item) {
                     return item.id;
                 };
for (var entry in metadata) {
     if (metadata.hasOwnProperty(entry)) {
         var varName = metadata[entry].variableName;
         if (metadata[entry].multipleValues === "false") {
             if (angular.isDefined(vm[varName]) && (vm[varName] !== null) && vm[varName].id !== null) {
                 filters.push(factory.buildEntry(metadata[entry].variableName, vm[varName].id, null, factory.filterOperators.textContains));
             }
         } else {
             if (angular.isDefined(vm[varName]) && (angular.isArray(vm[varName])) && (vm[varName].length > 0)) {
                 filters.push(factory.buildEntry(metadata[entry].variableName, null, vm[varName].map(mapFunction), factory.filterOperators.textContains));
             }
         }
     }
}
```

You can assign functions to variables and then treat that variable as a function

```js
var foo = function(){console.log('bar')};
foo();
```

In your case by assigning your mapping function to a variable, then passing that variable to the `.map()` gives you also an efficiency boost, because the function doesn't have to be re-instantiated every single time the loop runs. It can just re-use the same function over and over.

And as soon as the enclosing function ends which executes the loop, the variable ceases to exist.